# RUNSQLSTM - on IBM i - create or append data

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Is there syntax to perform a create or append in single statement.

```
CREATE TABLE MYLIB/MYFILE AS (                   

     SELECT                                            
     FIELD12,
     FIELD22,
     FIELD02,                                           
     FIELD23
    FROM MYLIB/MYDATA )
WITH DATA;   


RUNSQLSTM SRCFILE(MYLIB/QSQLSRC) SRCMBR(MYSQLSRC)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create the table with data if it doesn't exist, or just add additiona rows if the table is there?

No.

You could however create a stored procedure with the needed logic. Then simply call the stored procedure using RUNSQLSTM.